# Plot something with matplotlib/pyplot and save the plot only (centered, with equal aspect ratio and without axes or borders)

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I want to save just the resulting plot image to a file and wrote the following MCVE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["axes.facecolor"] = "red"
plt.rcParams["savefig.facecolor"] = "red"
plt.rcParams["savefig.bbox"] = "tight"
plt.rcParams["savefig.pad_inches"] = 0

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 0], "b-", linewidth="10")
plt.plot([1, 1], [0, 1], "b-", linewidth="10")
plt.plot([1, 0], [1, 1], "b-", linewidth="10")
plt.plot([0, 0], [1, 0], "b-", linewidth="10")

#plt.axis("equal")
#plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

[image: 1]

---

```
plt.axis("equal")
#plt.axis("off")
```

[image: 3]

---

```
#plt.axis("equal")
plt.axis("off")
```

[image: 2]

---

```
plt.axis("equal")
plt.axis("off")
```

[image: 4]

---

I found out about `bbox` and `pad_inches`. However, it's still not perfect. The axes seem to be hidden, not off completely - so the plot won't be centered. Additionally, I think I even need the axes to set a equal ratio or the rectangle won't be a square?

What I want is

[image: 5]

or

[image: 6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.rcParams["savefig.bbox"] = "tight"` adjusts the padding around the figure automatically. This seems to be undesired here. Leaving that out and creating a square figure with no margins (`plt.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)`) will allow to have the axes take all the space in the figure. There is then no need to set the aspect specifically any more, but of course for different cases that may still make sense.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["axes.facecolor"] = "red"
plt.rcParams["savefig.facecolor"] = "red"

plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
plt.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
plt.plot([0, 1, 1, 0,0], [0, 0,1,1,0], "b-", linewidth="10", solid_joinstyle="miter")

#plt.gca().set_aspect("equal",adjustable="box" ) # <- not needed
plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

To obtain the figure without red border, you could set the data margins to 0% (`plt.margins(0)`); however, because the line is half cut, it makes sense to double its linewidth to obtain the same blue border.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["axes.facecolor"] = "red"
plt.rcParams["savefig.facecolor"] = "red"

plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
plt.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
plt.plot([0, 1, 1, 0,0], [0, 0,1,1,0], "b-", linewidth=20, solid_joinstyle="miter")

#plt.gca().set_aspect("equal",adjustable="box" ) # <- not needed
plt.axis("off")
plt.margins(0.0)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The arguments are fractions of figure size. If you want the right side of the subplots (in this case the one subplot) to be tight at the right figure edge, you set `right=1` (meaning 100% of the figure width). The left subplot side is set to 0, so essentially there is no space left between the figure edge and the subplot. In other words `plt.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)` makes the subplot exactly as large as the figure itself. (This works well in this case because the figure has the same aspect as the subplot, both being square.)

Comment: Well, not really. If you keep the axis visible, half of it may still be inside the figure if the axis lines (spines) are not exactly one pixel wide - which they aren't by default. (Which again is different in jupyter notebook, where the dpi is set such that they are 1 pixel wide.) Confusing matter, bottom line: to be on the save side, you may still turn it off.

Comment: `axes.facecolor` can be omitted if you are only interested in the saved image. For showing on screen it needs to be there to have the axes background red.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a figure in a square shape and use `tight_layout()` to make the padding compact automatically.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creates a figure object of size 6x6 inches
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))

plt.rcParams["axes.facecolor"] = "red"
plt.rcParams["savefig.facecolor"] = "red"
plt.rcParams["savefig.bbox"] = "tight"
plt.rcParams["savefig.pad_inches"] = 0

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 0], "b-", linewidth="10")
plt.plot([1, 1], [0, 1], "b-", linewidth="10")
plt.plot([1, 0], [1, 1], "b-", linewidth="10")
plt.plot([0, 0], [1, 0], "b-", linewidth="10")

plt.axis("equal")
plt.axis("off")
fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

Comment: A quick fix is to use `fig.subplots_adjust(top=1.0, left=0.0, right=1.0, bottom=0.0)`. This will center your figure.